# How can i check that an elements exists in a array in firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my Firestore data]  I want to check whether a reference number in `Array` `Refnum` exists or not? How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

To test if a certain exact value exists in an array field, you can [use the `array-contains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

```
CollectionReference requestsRef = db.collection("upiPayRequests");

requestsRef.whereArrayContains("Refnum", 8888888888);
```

Comment: TypeError: db.collection(...).whereArrayContains is not a function